# Database efficiency: references/pointers from table to table

Tags: performance, database-design

I am working on learning databases and am unsure about something that doesn't seem to make any sense to me. In the relational model you are able to combine through references but always require a global sort of key in each table to be able to combine this information. That is obviously required in most cases, but I feel like in a perfect tree hierarchy set up of a database this is inefficient.

To explain this better I shall use the example of storing products in a database. Products have main categories and sub categories and these are very clear. (ie. Milk is a subcategory of Dairy which is a subcategory of Food, etc.)

I thought in cases like this the ability to store single or a list of references/pointers to tables in fields would take away a lot of search querying and storage requirements.

Here is a link to a simple pain layout I made to illustrate this:
[Image](http://postimg.org/image/v1cxd96b5/) (the table entry could have some command character like '|' after which it knows the following entry is a file directory so when the database initiates it knows to make a pointer there)

Since I am only learning to work with databases now I understand that I may just be missing some knowledge on the subject, but I don't seem to find anything when I try googling this problem. Any help explaining where to start or any confirmation that this may improve efficiency and where I could learn how to write this myself would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of "pointer" is useful only if the object you want to point to has a well-defined address that is at least as permanent as the pointer itself. If the address is less permanent, you could end up with a "dangling" pointer.

A row in the database does not necessarily have a permanent address.<sup>1</sup> By referencing the row through a logical value (instead of the physical address), the reference stays valid even when the row physically moves.<sup>2</sup> And to ensure that the value identifies exactly one row, it must be unique.<sup>3</sup>

As for storing the list of values (be it "pointers" or anything else) inside a single field, this violates the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF#Atomicity) and therefore the 1NF. There are very good reasons to avoid violating the 1NF, including the ability to maintain the referential integrity and utilize indexing. That being said, there are DBMSes that support arrays or even sub-tables within a single field, which may be useful on rare occasions.

---

*<sup>1</sup> For example, Oracle ROWID is constant as long as the row is not physically moved on disk, but that can happen in [many situations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/435123/533120) that are part of the normal database operation. So aside from putting severe restrictions on how your database is used, you couldn't rely on the ROWID staying constant over the lifetime of the rows that reference it (which could be as long as the lifetime of the database itself).*

*<sup>2</sup> I suppose it would be theoretically possible for a DBMS to keep track of all the pointers and update them when the row physically moves. However, I'm not aware of any DBMS that actually supports such "updatable" pointers in practice, probably because the underlying mechanism needed for that wouldn't be any more efficient than the standard "value-based" referencing.*

*<sup>3</sup> And must obviously be non-NULL. Saying that the attribute (or combination thereof) is "non-NULL and unique", is synonymous to saying it's a "key". Ideally, the key should also be immutable (so there is no need for a cascading referential action such as ON UPDATE CASCADE).*

Comment: Thank you very much, i am talking of that rare occasion. Could you refer me to a database system that supports this?

Comment: @user2255757 PosgreSQL supports [arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/arrays.html), Firebird too supports [arrays](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.Array), Oracle has [nested tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#CHDFDBGH) - these are the ones I know off the top of my head, there may be others...