# How to get the physical location(row id) of a record from DB using JPA+Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, criteria, rowid

I want to fetch the rowID of a table that does not have a primary key. I could get the rowId using sql query.But i think RowID is database specific.So it is not going to work if the database changes.

Could someone help me to get the rowID either using hql or criteria ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROWID is *virtual* column like any other. Try to search for VIRTUAL column support in Hibernate.

For example:
http://johnpremjeetpage.blogspot.cz/2009/06/mapping-hibernate-to-computed-columns.html

Last time I tried to use it in EclipseLink it failed. @ReadOnly annotation is ignored when combined with other annotations, and there was no way how to exclude a virtual column from generated insert statements.

Comment: Thank you. Can ROWID for a record change without any notification? Should we not use ROWID to fetch the records?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435109/what-can-cause-an-oracle-rowid-to-change.